# ArcGIS API for JavaScript - check if a polygon exists in a polygon feature layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a polygon feature layer and a polygon geometry. How do I find out if the feature layer contains the polygon, as in exact shape of the polygon?

I did see the geometry engine, but that doesn't contain a method for knowing if exact shape exists at same place. Both datasets have same spatial reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a [QueryTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/querytask-amd.html) on the layer, and specify the geometry of the polygon in the Query's [geometry clause](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/query-amd.html#geometry) and a `SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS` for the query type.

This would return any geometries from the layer which intersect with the polygon.

You could then examine those to see whether they had matching start/end coordinates, number of vertices, etc. Or [convert each polygon to JSON](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/polygon-amd.html#tojson) and compare with the original polygon.